# Can i get access token from facebook without using AppId?

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook C# SDK 5.3.2 for desktop application. I created an application on the facebook to get AppId. I can get accsess token using this appid. And i can also post my facebook wall. But i also want to post my friends's wall. How can i do that without using AppId? My senerio is add all friends to app getting accsess token and post mesages to their walls using this tokens. Is that possible? How can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get authentication from users in order to retrieve an access token that will work for them.  You **have** to use your APP_ID in order to authenticate your application with a user.

Comment: can you give me a sample code to get authentication from users? I am using facebook C# SDK 5.3.2

Comment: I have no knowlege of C# or its facebook SDK. The [facebook authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) details exactly how to retrieve access tokens. The examples are in PHP but the urls stay the same.  You first have to authenticate the user : `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL` and then you can request the access token - `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET`

Comment: can i use this authenticate method for another facebook user except mine? And which information do i need for the user. (user name , pwd  etc)

Comment: You'll need to request permission from your user to access his/her friends information depending on what information you are looking for. for example you can request the `friends_birthday` permission to see friends birthdays.  And yes - you use the same method for friends like you would for yourself : `/FRIEND_ID/feed` or `/FRIEND_ID/photos`, etc...

Comment: thank you Lix. I have a another issue now. .Net webbrowser control doesn't clear cache. And i didn't get facebook login screen for second request from inside of webbrowser control.

Comment: Sorry friend - i have zero knowledge in .NET - i'm a php man :P
Try searching for the solution in previous questions...